# generate all permutations of nxn grid of s options

Tags: algorithm

i am trying to make an algorithm that will give me all of the permations of a nxn grid where the cells can only be in set s.  So for example if i had a 4x4 grid and the cells could only be 1 to 4 how would i go about generating all of the permutations of this grid.  I am not good at dynamic programming have pondered this all day and i cant figure it out.  My initial thought was to create a for loop for 1 to 16 (number of cells in 4x4 grid) and then a nested loop of 1 to 4 but this of course only gives me 64 and i know that it should be 4^16 so that is not write but i cant seem to figure out how to code this.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`4^16` is quite a big number. Are you sure you want all permutations?

A recursive procedure would create all different grids:

```
xMin = 0;
xMax = n – 1;
yMin = 0;
yMax = n – 1;
int [,] grid;

void proc(int x, int y)
{
    for (int s = sMin; s <= sMax; s++)
    {
        grid[x, y] = s;
        if (x == xMax)
        {
            //  next row
            if (y == yMax)
                //  end of recursion
                output(grid);
            else
                proc(xMin, y + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            //  next column
            proc(x + 1, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Start recursion:

```
proc(xMin, yMin);
```